# Python xlrd string comparison against a cell

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am new to Python & xlrd and I am having trouble performing a (seemingly) simple string comparison:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('/home/Y725271/Desktop/test_report.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

# Iterate all of the column names and see if col apple exists
col_len = sheet.row_len(0)
for i in range(col_len):
    col = sheet.cell_value(0,i)
    if col.lower() == "apple"
        print "match"
    else
        print "mismatch"
```

When I run the code through the interpreter, I get the following error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    if col.lower() == "apple"
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? I'm comparing two strings, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust the interpreter and read up on the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)

Change

```
if col.lower() == "apple"
```

into

```
if col.lower() == "apple":
```

Comment: Thank you! Python noob mistake! ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO, don't forget to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and upvote/accept the answer if it helped you. Keep them posts coming...